# Normilizing data in a huge XLS file before cross-reference checking the data

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, normalization, xls

I have a huge **14MB XLS file** with unnormalized data like shown in the attached picture. (fake data to illustrate the point here)

I need to make a semantic integrity check. For each row (event) cross reference if it sends data to some other event, if it does, than there must also be an entry in the "gets data from" column of the receiving event and vice versa. The problem the data is not normalized but separated by semicolon.

[![Dataset without normalisation][1]][1]

[[image: 2]]

***Question: What is the best solution for normalization and then semantic reference?***

**Possible Solution A:**

1. Save to CSV-File, write a script that would read each line and decompose the data. If it finds a ";" in any row, it would add a new line with that data to the new file.
2. Write another script in Java, JavaScript, Python that would do the semantic reference on the normalized set

**Possible Solution B:**
Just write a VBA-Macro that would take each row (each event) read out the "sends to" column and immediately check if there is a corresponding entry in the "gets data from" column of the found event.

Comment: I suggest you try both on a subset and see which works better with your particular data set and requirements.

Comment: Here is how I think about the VBA solution: The easiest way to solve this is by using a map. As far as I know I would need to build my own map data structure in VBA and then make sure that it is performant. If I use python, java or javascript, I would be able to use the native performance optimized map implementation. I would prolly not even need to normalize the data in advance. Just read the data and feed it into the map structure.